# How are ERC 721 based DAO created?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20, erc721

I am trying to create a NFT DAO, ERC 721 based after ERC 721 vote feature came in recently. Tally is the only tool allowing for that. But I wanted to try and experience traditional DAO creation first.

So I have been trying my hands on to create a DAO. I know about the basics, I know what a DAO is and how it works. I have read about all the tools that help in building it from snapshot to Aragon, Daostack, zodiac and others. I have also gone through DAO Masters

What I didn't understand is, how do people join the DAO.

I mean, I created a DAO over rinkeby network using Aragon, I was the only participant at first, now how will any other address join the DAO? I created a token inside the DAO itself but what next? Similar steps are for daohaus.

I tried looking for tutorials but I couldn't find an end to end one. There is a flood of articles that tell about how there are tools for DAO creation but the next steps are no where to be found.

Intuitively, This is how I thought DAO creation tools work before trying them.

DAO Name, Symbol, Address, Details (proposals, voting, cooldown etc).
DAO Governance Token details (if ERC20, then details like total supply and price etc.)
Initial addresses (members) of DAO and their Shares/Token allocation.
Option to buy tokens (with a limit enforced) to become a part of the DAO.
The money from the token purchase is now part of the treasury.
Next steps are pursued like proposals and voting.
My aim is to create a NFT DAO, where each NFT = 1 Vote and the NFT is an ERC 721 token. A limit on how many tokens can be owned by a single wallet. Purchase/Mint of the NFT makes them a member of the DAO and the amount used to purchase/mint comes to the DAO treasury. The number of ERC 721 tokens and their price is still under discussion but it'll most likely be 40-50k. I have also weighed the options and came to the conclusion that I want to use ERC 721 and not ERC 20.

Any help regarding this will be helpful (help ~ pointing towards resources, tutorials, whitepaper, articles, an explanation or pointing out what a fool I am and how I should have read/watched/understood/referred to a previous question, topic, documentation (which I must have missed unintentionally.))

Note : I want to create everything over Ethereum Blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

snapshot+safesnap may be a good solution

Comment: If a question can be answered by naming a tool or lib, then it is off-topic and should be closed and deleted. If it cannot not be answered by naming a tool then you should not. Instead please provide an answer according to [answer]. Demonstrating how what you mention can be used to solve the problem would be one way to do so.